# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined. Node.js in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio

I am trying to program a web application in Visual Studio with Node.js and React.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
```

but I have got an error in the console of the web browser (Google Chrome).
The error is that "require" is not defined so I can't use the fs ("File System") of  Node.js, path and express neither.

[image: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined]

This is the rest of the code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var staticPath = path.join(__dirname, '/');
app.use(express.static(staticPath));

app.set('port', process.env.PORT ||  3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port', function() {
  console.log('listening')
})
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between server-side code and client-side code.  You can't do that.

Comment: Specifically, you need to run your server-side code as the server using Node.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your question. You are more likely to get some help if you can include the error text or code formatted directly in your question instead of posting screenshots. It makes it easier for folks trying to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Node.JS is a server-side technology, not a browser technology. Thus, Node-specific calls, like require(), do not work in the browser. u may have to install proper node packages